# Prevent Removing VF Page From Page Layout?

Tags: page-layout, visualforce

Admin users have the ability to modify the `Page Layout` and can easily remove a specific `Visualforce Page` from it. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? If not, what steps should I take to prevent Admin users from removing the `Visualforce Page`?

Comment: Honestly: does it not make more sense to limit your admin users to strictly those that know what they are doing ?

Comment: I agree with @SamuelDeRycke,  what is the use case you see here?

Comment: Mod comment to all: I reopend the question because it is not offtopic. Please also only down-vote to express opinion on the quality of the question format, not in disagreeing with the aimed-for result.

Answer (score 5):

There is no mechanism to make a `Visualforce Page` "required" on a `Page Layout`. You are going to have to rethink your requirements and approach this from an admin training perspective. If you **train your admins** not to remove this page from the layout, you should be able to **trust them** to follow your instruction as long as they are capable professionals.

Comment: +1 I totally agree with @adrian on this. Why would you want to refrain an admin from doing administrative tasks ?

Comment: If you cannot trust your admin, you cannot trust anyone.